# Powershell - TLS1.2 support

Tags: api, rest, powershell, tls1.2

Do you know if there is a way to enable TLS1.2 in powershell (ie. for invoke-webrequest or invoke-restmethod)?

By default it looks like Powershell uses TLS1.0, which is not compatible with all our web services.

/Patrik

Answer (score 22):

There was!

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

/Patrik

Comment: @PatrickJ That does not work on Win7/PS2.0

Comment: @SebMa I imagine this is the case because the PS version does not support Tls12. Maybe updating .Net could help, but not likely.