# Unable to access remote server to install Chocolatey

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I'm trying to install Chocolatey using Powershell (run as administrator) as per the instructions on the Chocolatey website. I've changed the ExecutionPolicy by running:

Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned

The error I'm getting is:

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U25Ci.png)

I've tried the workaround mentioned but it is not working:
[error when trying to install chocolatey via powershell : cannot connect to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53390523/error-when-trying-to-install-chocolatey-via-powershell-cannot-connect-to-remot)

thanks in advance!